# Terraform Unsupported block type error for "aws_cloudformation_stack"

Tags: terraform, circleci

I'm setting "Deploying to AWS ECR/ECS(below link)",and I finish 1-4.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ecs-ecr/#section=deployment

```
$ terraform plan

Error: Unsupported block type

  on terraform.tf line 30, in resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "vpc":
  30:   parameters {

Blocks of type "parameters" are not expected here. Did you mean to define
argument "parameters"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

This is my code.

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "vpc" {
  name = "${local.aws_vpc_stack_name}"
  template_body = "${file("cloudformation-templates/public-vpc.yml")}"
  capabilities = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"]
  parameters {
    ClusterName = "${local.aws_ecs_cluster_name}"
    ExecutionRoleName = "${local.aws_ecs_execution_role_name}"
  }
}
```

What should I do to successfully "terraform plan" ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of

```
parameters {
  ClusterName = "${local.aws_ecs_cluster_name}"
  ExecutionRoleName = "${local.aws_ecs_execution_role_name}"
}
```

try

```
parameters = {
  ClusterName = "${local.aws_ecs_cluster_name}"
  ExecutionRoleName = "${local.aws_ecs_execution_role_name}"
}
```

The first is interpreted as a block, the second as an argument. Hence the error.